# how can we insert hash type data in redis sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect, hashset

while utilising the redis sink connector. We wish to add hash-type data to Redis. but we obtain string type data.

is there any possible to insert data in hash type using smt in  settings.

```
{
    "ADDRESSBOOKLIST": {
        "contactId": 123456,
        "userId": 112584,
        "companyName": "Other",
        "firstName": sam,
        "lastName": william,
        "contactType": "CARRIER"
    }
}
```

we changed the KEY_FORMAT = 'json' in presistent table. after that we get the data like string type. we want data in hash type.

Answer (score 1):

set value:

```
HSET myhash key value
```

get value:

```
HGET myhash key value
```

so you can do like this:
Serialize **{ "contactId": 123456, "userId": 112584, "companyName": "Other", "firstName": sam, "lastName": william, "contactType": "CARRIER" }** as value

```
HSET myhash ADDRESSBOOKLIST value

HGET myhash ADDRESSBOOKLIST
```

than Deserialize it.

or，

use new version redis tools to get json data.